# Tkinter Rectangle connected to Keypress

Tags: python, animation, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

The following program draws a rectangle in the center of the canvas. The rectangle is supposed to get wider when the right arrow key is pressed, and narrower when the left arrow key is pressed.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=300, bg="#000000")
canvas.pack()
x1 = 150
y1 = 100
x2 = 250
y2 = 200

class ResizeRect:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        self.rect = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,1,1)
    def draw(self):
        canvas.delete(self.rect)
        self.rect = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2,
                                            outline="#00B000", width=2)
        
    def narrower(self):
        self.x1 = self.x1 + 5
        self.x2 = self.x2 - 5
        
    def wider(self):
        self.x1 = self.x1 - 5
        self.x2 = self.x2 + 5
        
r = ResizeRect(150, 100, 250, 200)
r.draw()

def left(event):
    r.narrower()
    r.draw()
    
def right(event):
    r.wider()
    r.draw()


canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', left)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', right)
```

My teacher told me that I need to add the 'self' keyword to the parameters in the draw function but I don't know what he means. (I can't ask him more because he's in a bad mood right now.). Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is unusual to create mix of OOP and a procedureal solution like you did. Why did you do this how you did it ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.  What is an OOP and what do you mean 'how did I do it'?

Comment: Your teacher is right about adding self. In the create_rectangle function `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, and `y2`, are undefined. Those are local to the function, not the ones assigned in your class. You need to add `self.` before each of them.

Comment: You don't need to delete and recreate the rectangle, use `canvas.coords(self.rect, self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2)` to replace `canvas.delete(self.rect)` and `self.rect = canvas.create(...)` inside `draw()`.  And add `outline='#00B000'` and `width=2` in `create_rectangle(...)` inside `__init__()`.

Comment: @acw1668 `canvas.move(id,x,y)` is even easier

Comment: @scotty3785 What OP wants is to resize the rectangle, so `move()` cannot be used.

Comment: @acw1668 Never mind then :P